# MQTT Paho Python Client subscriber, how subscribe forever?

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

Try to simple subscribe without disconnect to a Mosquitto broker to get all messages from devices that are publishing data in a specific topic, save them in a BD and Post them to a php that do "staff".

Here is my subscribe.py

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from mqtt_myapp import *

topic="topic/#"                 # MQTT broker topic
myclient="my-paho-client"           # MQTT broker My Client
user="user"                     # MQTT broker user
pw="pass"                       # MQTT broker password
host="localhost"                # MQTT broker host
port=1883                       # MQTT broker port
value="123"                     # somethin i need for myapp

def on_connect(mqttc, userdata, rc):
    print('connected...rc=' + str(rc))
    mqttc.subscribe(topic, qos=0)

def on_disconnect(mqttc, userdata, rc):
    print('disconnected...rc=' + str(rc))

def on_message(mqttc, userdata, msg):
    print('message received...')
    print('topic: ' + msg.topic + ', qos: ' + 
          str(msg.qos) + ', message: ' + str(msg.payload))
    save_to_db(msg)
    post_data(msg.payload,value)

def on_subscribe(mqttc, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print('subscribed (qos=' + str(granted_qos) + ')')

def on_unsubscribe(mqttc, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print('unsubscribed (qos=' + str(granted_qos) + ')')

mqttc = mqtt.Client(myclient)
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.on_unsubscribe = on_unsubscribe
mqttc.username_pw_set(user,pw)
mqttc.connect(host, port, 60)
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Here is my mqtt_myapp.py:

```
import MySQLdb
import requests # pip install requests

url = "mydomain/data_from_broker.php"

def save_to_db(msg):
    with db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MQTT_LOGS (topic, payload) VALUES (%s,%s)", (msg.topic, msg.payload))
        except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            print('excepttion BD ' + e)
            return None

def post_data(payload,value):
    datos = {'VALUE': value,'data-from-broker': payload}
    r = requests.post(url, datos)
    r.status_code
    print('response POST' + str(r.status_code))

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user_db","pass_db","db" )
```

When I run my python script on background with `python -t mqtt_subscribe.py &` I get messages publish for other clients, but **after some hours of my subscribe.py script running, socket error happens.**

Mosquito.log:

```
 ...
    1475614815: Received PINGREQ from my-paho-client
    1475614815: Sending PINGRESP to my-paho-client
    1475614872: New connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 1883.
    1475614872: Client device1 disconnected.
    1475614872: New client connected from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as device1(c0, k0, u'user1').
    1475614872: Sending CONNACK to device1(0, 0)
    1475614873: Received PUBLISH from device1(d0, q1, r0, m1, 'topic/data', ... (33 bytes))
    1475614873: Sending PUBACK to device1 (Mid: 1)
    1475614873: Sending PUBLISH to my-paho-client (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'topic/data', ... (33 bytes))
    1475614874: Received DISCONNECT from device1
    1475614874: Client device1 disconnected.
...
    1475625566: Received PINGREQ from my-paho-client
    1475625566: Sending PINGRESP to my-paho-client
    1475625626: Received PINGREQ from my-paho-client
    1475625626: Sending PINGRESP to my-paho-client
    1475625675: New connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 1883.
    1475625675: Client device1 disconnected.
    1475625675: New client connected from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as device1 (c0, k0, u'user1').
    1475625675: Sending CONNACK to device1 (0, 0)
    1475625677: Received PUBLISH from device1 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'topic/data', ... (33 bytes))
    1475625677: Sending PUBACK to device1 (Mid: 1)
    1475625677: Sending PUBLISH to my-paho-client (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'topic/data', ... (33 bytes))
    1475625677: Socket error on client my-paho-client, disconnecting.
    1475625677: Received DISCONNECT from device1
...
```

What could be the problem? Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code in the method "on_message" throws an exception and you do not catch it, you will be disconnected.
Try uncommenting all statements except the print statements. Probably one of the following statements is throwing an exception.

```
 save_to_db(msg)
 post_data(msg.payload,value)
```

Comment: And where I should code my "save_to_db" if I want to catch the "on_message" event?

Comment: you can code there, just make sure, that you catch all exceptions there, if you do not want to be disconnected.

Comment: Try to understand, so just because I dont catch exceptions, the script disconnected? Even if I catch the exception and do nothing script doesn't stops? SebastianK, could you give me a reference to study this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: I had this issue with the java implementation and i guess the behaviour is the same for python. Have a look at the javadoc [link](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/index.html) --> MqttCallback --> messageArrived. There this behaviour is decribed.

Comment: "the script disconnected" - I think what happens is that the uncaught exception causes the thread handling the MQTT connection to die, which breaks the TCP connection, i.e. you aren't subscribed any more because you aren't connected any more. If you (as you always should when connecting over unreliable/unpredictable networks) use try/except judiciously (i.e. don't simply blanket ignore all exceptions, IMO that's even worse than not using try/except) you will be able to ensure that the thread doesn't die when the exception happens.

Answer (score -1):

While inserting into DB, use `?` instead of `%s`.
[link for reference](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-sqlite-in-python)

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users(name, phone, email, password)
                  VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (name1,phone1, email1, password1))
```

Comment: That's for sqlite, not for MySQLdb.